# Problem 4 chapter 2: functional analysis (Rudin)

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, functional-analysis, lp-spaces

> $L^1$, $L^2$: usual Lebesgue spaces on the unit interval. Show that $L^2$ is of the first category (meager) in $L^1$, in three ways:
>
> (a) Show that $F_n:=\{f:\int|f|^2 \leq n\}$ is closed in $L^1$ but has empty interior.
>
> (b)Put $g_n=n$ on $[0,n^{-3}]$, and show that $\int fg_n \rightarrow 0$ $\forall f \in L^2$ , but not for every $f\in L^1$.
>
> (c) Note that the inclusion map  of $L^2$ into $L^1$ is continuous but not onto.
>
> Do the same for $L^p$ and $L^q$ if $p<q$.

Comment: What have you tried? Copying an exercise verbatim from a book, with no thoughts of your own is not very helpful.

Comment: @mrf, I have tried to solved this problem. Can you give me some idea?

Answer (score 3):

For each question, there are two sub-questions: 1. Why the assertion is true? and 2. Why does this one give the result?

a. 1. Show sequential closeness (as we are in a metric context) by Fatou's lemma. What happens if we assume that $F_n$ has a non-empty interior (in $L^1$)?
 2 It's by definition.

b. 1. Use the fact that $\{f_n\}$ is bounded in $L^2$ and that simple functions are dense in $L^2$.

c. 1. It follows from a well-known integral inequality. Take an integrable function which is not square integrable. 
  2. There is a related theorem earlier in the book.

Comment: Thanks for susgesting ideas. I will try this problem.

Comment: @user52523 Any progress?

Comment: I have some tried but i still have no idea for a, and c. With b, i solve it in the following way:
b, $\int |fg_n|\le\alpha\int|g_n|$, but we have: $\int g_n=n.1/n^3 \rightarrow 0, $ so is $\int fg_n$

Could you check out for me, please. Thanks you so much.

Comment: I just finished this problem. Thank you so much for helping me.